Isomorphisms between Hom-sets in abelian tensor categories.
Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a tensor category, which is abelian. Assume we know from theory that $\text{Hom}(A,B) \cong \text{Hom}(C,D)$. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is then enriched over $\mathbf{Ab}$, it follows that the hom-sets (assuming locally small) have a group structure. Does it follow that $\text{Hom}(A,B) \cong \text{Hom}(C,D)$ as abelian groups? I.e. that $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ and $\text{Hom}(C,D)$ are isomorphic in $\mathbf{Ab}$?
I am particular interested in the application to such canonical isomorphisms as $\text{Hom}(T \otimes X,Y) \simeq \text{Hom}(T,\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y))$ where $\underline{\text{Hom}}(A,B)$ is the internal hom (given that it exists; so for example in rigid abelian tensor categories).
Edit: I am not sure this holds generally, but perhaps it holds atleast if we have that the isomorphism comes from an adjunction?

What do you mean "know from theory that $\operatorname{Hom}(A, B) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(C, D)$"? Obviously this is false if you only require that there exist some bijection without any further constraints; I'll leave it to you to come up with an example in $\mathrm{Ab}$ where the two sets have the same cardinality but are not isomorphic as groups.

By "known from theory", I mean that we can know that generally in a tensor category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ we have that $\text{Hom}(A,B) \cong \text{Hom}(C,D)$. A tensor category does not need to be an abelian category.

Why the downvote?

The situation in your two paragraphs is quite different: in the first paragraph you have an isomorphism of sets (so there is no reason at all to expect that it respects the group structure) while in the second paragraph you have a natural isomorphism of functors $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$. You generalised the question a bit too far.

Yes, sure, there is a difference. Does naturality affect whether or not they are isomorphic as groups?

I don't know, but it could even be the case that the answer is yes for the specific case of the tensor-hom adjunction (that seems at least plausible to me) but no for a general natural isomorphism.

hm, perhaps, I mean, maybe the fact that it is an adjunction affects the answer, in that specific case.

Your general question is much too general but your specific question about adjunctions has the following positive answer.

Proposition: Let $C, D$ be additive categories ($\text{Ab}$-enriched with finite biproducts) and $F : C \to D, G : D \to C$ a pair of adjoint functors between their underlying categories, so we have a natural isomorphism $\text{Hom}(F(c), d) \cong \text{Hom}(c, G(d))$ of sets. Then this natural isomorphism is automatically an isomorphism of abelian groups.

This follows from the fact that in an additive category the abelian group structure on homsets is uniquely determined by the behavior of finite biproducts (this is surprising and not obvious; for a thorough discussion of this see my old blog post A meditation on semiadditive categories), together with the observations that

The Hom functor preserves colimits in the first variable and limits in the second variable, so preserves finite biproducts in both variables,
$F$ is a left adjoint so preserves colimits and in particular finite biproducts, and
$G$ is a right adjoint so preserves limits and in particular finite biproducts.

The same argument also shows that $F$ and $G$ are automatically additive functors in the sense of preserving the abelian group structure on homsets, and in fact we can show that a functor between additive categories preserves the abelian group structure on homsets iff it preserves finite biproducts.
These arguments crucially rely on functoriality and don't say anything about the situation in which we just have a bijection $\text{Hom}(a, b) \cong \text{Hom}(c, d)$ which is not related to a functor; in this level of generality there's no reason to expect anything.

Wow, great answer, thanks :)
